# Issue with row always being undefined

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am working on a Node.js application that interacts with a Google Sheet using the google-spreadsheet library. I have a function statsUpdate(id, is_correct) that updates the statistics for a given ID in the Google Sheet. However, I am facing an issue where the row.tgid value is always undefined, even though there are values in the corresponding column in the Google Sheet.

Here is my code:

```js
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require("google-spreadsheet");
const { JWT } = require("google-auth-library");
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

dotenv.config();

const SCOPES = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
];

const jwt = new JWT({
    email: process.env.SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    key: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.split(String.raw`\n`).join('\n'),
    scopes: SCOPES,
});
  
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(
    process.env.GOOGLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
    jwt,
);

async function saveId(id) {
    //saving id to sheet
}

async function statsUpdate(id, is_correct) {
    try {
        await doc.loadInfo();
        const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0];
        const rows = await sheet.getRows();

        for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            const row = rows[i];
            console.log(id, row.tgid);
            if (row.tgid === id) {
                if (is_correct) {
                    row.correct_answers += 1;
                }
                row.answers += 1;
                await row.save();
                break;
            }
        }

        console.log(`Stats updated for ID: ${id}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error while updating stats for ID: ${id}, error`);
    }
}
```

I have already checked for any hidden characters or spaces in the Google Sheet and made sure that the values in the sheet and the id variable have the same format. However, the issue persists.

Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect in your Google Spreadsheet? And, in your script, when you put `console.log(["tgid" in rows[0], rows[0].tgid])` just after the line of `const rows = await sheet.getRows();`, what values will you obtain? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike console.log(["tgid" in rows[0], rows[0].tgid]) outputs [ false, undefined ], I want to get the id of the telegram account that is stored in the tgid column, for example 1111111111

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. From `console.log(["tgid" in rows[0], rows[0].tgid]) outputs [ false, undefined ], I want to get the id of the telegram account that is stored in the tgid column, for example 1111111111`, I understood the value from `console.log(["tgid" in rows[0], rows[0].tgid])`. But, unfortunately, I cannot still understand the sample input and output situations you expect in your Google Spreadsheet. I apologize for this again.

Comment: Or, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to test your situation.